# Rewrite url for seo friendly htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to rewrite this in SEO friendly url.

From - `www.example.com/section.php?name=website`

To - `www.example.com/section/website`

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ section.php?type=$1&service=$2 [NC,L]
```

I am fetching data using GET method in section.php and pass to the another page but after opening sub folder like `www.example.com/{foldername}` it returns to the section.php

Thanks. I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps me

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?type=$1&service=$2
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for rewrite to section.php as per OP's request.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ section.php?name=$1 [L]
```